# If else statement trouble javascript

Tags: javascript

My goal here is to check x and see if it is less than or equal to 100, & if it is more than or equal to 0. IF true: alert("entered grade is valid") if false: alert("entered grade is not valid").

I do not understand  what i'm doing wrong, it just keeps returning any number ( for example 50, which meets both requirements) inputted as false.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<title> Bitar_Grade Calculator </title>

<head>
<script> 
var x = document.orderForm.stuentgrade.value;

function checkGrade()
{
    if (x>=0 && x<=100)
    { 
        alert("Entered grade is valid!");
    }
    else
    { 
            alert("Entered grade is invalid!");
    }
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form>
Please enter the students grade:<br>
<input type="number" name="studentgrade"><br>
</form>
<button onclick="checkGrade()"> Enter</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening your console? (hit F12). One error will be apparent. Also, you should be re-assigning `x` every time the function is called or it's always going to be whatever the value was when the page opened.

Comment: Your `x` value is set when the page is loaded and it is never changed when the form is updated

Comment: How do i go about reassigning x?

Comment: @AlexBitar `x = whatever you want to assign to it`.

Answer (score 1):

You have some typo and errors in your code

See working function

```
function checkGrade() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName('studentgrade')[0].value
    if (x>=0 && x<=100) { 
        alert("Entered grade is valid!");
    }
    else { 
        alert("Entered grade is invalid!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the reading of the form field inside the function that does the checking (and add a bit more checking for valid values), like this;

```
function checkGrade()
{
    var x = parseInt(document.orderForm.studentgrade.value);
    if (x && x>=0 && x<=100)
    { 
        alert("Entered grade is valid!");
    }
    else
    { 
            alert("Entered grade is invalid!");
    }
}
```

However, **note** that this is not a full solution to validating intereg values, so somebody entering "3million" will still be validated as "3"

Answer (score 0):

x is out of scope, you have no form name "orderForm", and theres a spelling mistake in your object name, stuentform...

Give your input an id, and do something like:

```
function checkGrade()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('studentgrade').value;

    if ( x>=0 && x<=100 )
    { 
        alert("Entered grade is valid!");
    }
    else
    { 
        alert("Entered grade is invalid!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` isn't out of scope. You can use variables from a parent scope.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNNXWP does not work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxxmeK does.

Comment: Yes it does. `x` just isn't being reassigned. [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNNYqq)

Comment: the x the function is using is the one thats defined inside the function.
in your example the x thats defined outside the function is not used or seen by the function. its a different scope.

Comment: No it's not. [It's the same `x`](https://jsfiddle.net/36jqoakg/). You should read about [closures.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: by "being reassigned" you mean that x doesn't actually have a value until its set by the actual function call. crossed wires and confusion.

essentially x is not set outside the function. x is only set when the function is called (in OPs question).

you are correct in that its not a scope issue.